# Minimize $\displaystyle\sum_{1 \le i < j \le 95} a_i a_j$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Each of the numbers $a_1,$ $a_2,$ $\dots,$ $a_{95}$ is $\pm 1.$ Find the smallest possible positive value of $$\sum_{1 \le i < j \le 95} a_i a_j.$$

---

My guess is that the answer should be $1$, but I'm not sure if this can happen, and I'm also not sure how you can prove it. I would greatly appreciate any help!!

Thanks!!

Comment: That looks a lot like cross terms in $(a_1+a_2+\cdots a_{95})^2

Comment: Indeed, $\sum_{1 \le i < j \le 95} a_i a_j = \frac12\big( \sum_{1\le k\le 95} a_k \big)^2 - \frac12\sum_{1\le k\le 95} a_k^2$ makes the problem much more transparent.

Comment: The order of the $a_i$ doesn't matter since you have all possible pairwise products of them.  So a possible approach is: (1) Say $k$ terms are equal to $+1$ and $95-k$ terms are equal to $-1$; what's the sum, as a function of $k$?  (2) Find the integer $k$ for which this is smallest but still positive.

Comment: Hint: this equals to $\binom{95}2-2t(95-t)$ where $t$ is the number of $1$s

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!! I really appreciate it!